# Python find first occurrence in Pandas dataframe column 2 below threshold and return column 1 value same row using NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scipy

I have a dataframe as below:

```
0.1   0.65
0.2   0.664
0.3   0.606
0.4   0.587
0.5   0.602
0.6   0.59
0.7   0.53
```

I have to find the first occurence below **0.6** in column 2 and return the value of the column 1 on same row. In that example the returned value would be **0.4**.

How could I do this using **Numpy** or **SciPy** ?

the code is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([*zip([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [0.65, 0.664, 0.606 ,0.587 ,0.602,0.59,0.53])])

threshold = 0.6
var = df[df[1] < threshold].head(1)[0]
res = var.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Instead of iloc, try loc or iat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use masking and the `df.head()` function to get the first occurrence given the threshold.

```
df[df[1] < threshold].head(1)[0]

3    0.4
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

### Update

To use numpy, you need to convert the pandas to numpy and use `np.where`.

```
array = df.values

array[np.where(array[:,1] < 0.6)][0,0]
0.4
```

To compare the performance, we will time the two sets of codes.

```
# Pandas style
def function1(df):
    return df[df[1] < threshold].head(1)[0]

# Numpy style
def function2(df):
    array = df.values

    return array[np.where(array[:,1] < 0.6)][0,0]

%timeit function1(df)
322 µs ± 6.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit function2(df)
11.8 µs ± 209 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: many thanks Kevin. I discover Numpy could be faster but I struggle to code this. So I have updated my question again

Comment: @OlM is this what you need?

Comment: many thanks again. np 27 times faster !